# Framework not found GoogleMapsCore

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the Google Maps framework in my iOS app. But I cant seem to understand what is causing the error: Framework not found GoogleMapsCore.

Yes I know that it can't find that module. But I can see it in the Pods folder. See the image below.
[image]

I even added the link to that folder in the Framework Search Path.. see image below.
[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: did u managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is an indication that the Pods projects is not properly built. The best way to solve this is to remove the GoogleMaps pods from your Podfile, run `pod install`. This will remove the GoogleMaps Framework. Then edit the Podfile again, add the GoogleMaps framework and run `pod install` again. This will reinstall the pods, and regenerate the Pods Project linking all your frameworks properly to your app. It almost always works for this error - `Framework not found`.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be those red files.  See all those red filenames? They are missing from the project. You need to build them.
Look up cocoapods and follow the instructions to create your workspace file. [it's just one simple install command]

**Always** from now on, when working on this project, instead of 
**ProjectName.xcodeproj** (blue avatar) you should double-click on the **ProjectName.xcworkspace** (white avatar) file.  That will open the project in  Xcode.  And the filenames should no longer be red.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me I needed to remove armv7s from the valid Architectures. I guess GoogleMaps (2.3.1), which is what I am using, does not build against that architecture.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Delete your PODS folder, and run pod install again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before posting an answer, check to make sure your not posting the same answer as someone else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29815041)